# Парсинг Python: поиск элемента у которого нет потомков

Tags: html, css, python, xpath

Всем привет, необходимо вытащить p, где имеется текст 5-10, и 11-17

**Код:**

```
  <td>
        <br>
        <p>
            <font class="font-subject">Основы автоматизации проектно-конструкторских работ</font>
            <br>
            <font class="font-classroom">
                <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmouseup="GoToTheLink(2, 3, 192)">2-120</a>
            </font>
            <font class="font-teacher"></font>
        </p>
        <p>
            <font class="font-teacher">Лекция + практика</font>
        </p>
        <font class="font-teacher">
            <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmouseup="GoToTheLink(2, 1, '2318!ФАДЭТ!3')">АС-306</a>
        </font>
        <p>5-10</p>
        <br>
        <p>
            <font class="font-subject">Основы автоматизации проектно-конструкторских работ</font>
            <br>
            <font class="font-classroom">
               <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmouseup="GoToTheLink(2, 3, 339)">2-510</a>
            </font>
            <font class="font-teacher"></font>
        </p>
        <p>
            <font class="font-teacher">Лекция + практика</font>
        </p>
        <font class="font-teacher">
            <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmouseup="GoToTheLink(2, 1, '2318!ФАДЭТ!3')">АС-306</a>
        </font>
        <p>11-17</p>
    </td>
```

Так как имеются и другие элементы p, единственным возможным найти эти элементы, это поиск у родителя элементы p, у которых нет потомков.

**Вопрос**: можно ли его найти с помощью css-селектора? (ну если нельзя, то хотя бы Xpath, если возможно).

Для парсинга использую lxml (cssselect)

**Update**
Возможные шаблоны текста:

```
5-10
1, 2-10, 12-15
2, 4, 8
2
4-6, 8, 10-14
```

Comment: Вам принципиально использование lxml? Я бы предложил вам для этих целей использовать BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов ну напишите на bs4, я конвертирую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Через чистый css-инструментарий сейчас нет возможности выцепить элемент, в котором отсутствуют дочерние элементы: к сожалению, [:empty](http://htmlbook.ru/css/empty) в данном случае не подходит.

Решение через xpath: `//p[not(child::*)]`

Comment: о, спасибо, хотя бы через xpath

Comment: только вроде нужно искать без // иначе ищется вообще все элементы на странице

Comment: В зависимости от полного исходного кода страницы :)
понимал, что в задаче приложен лишь кусок страницы, и ориентировался на то, чтоб xpath-выражение вне зависимости от неизвестной части DOM вернуло массив нод, в котором точно будут искомые ноды, при корректном отсечении всех излишних нод в рамках приложенного кода

Answer (score 1):

С использованием BeautifulSoup и регулярных выражений:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """
<td>
    <br>
    <p>
        <font class="font-subject">Основы автоматизации проектно-конструкторских работ</font>
        <br>
        <font class="font-classroom">
            <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmouseup="GoToTheLink(2, 3, 192)">2-120</a>
        </font>
        <font class="font-teacher"></font>
    </p>
    <p>
        <font class="font-teacher">Лекция + практика</font>
    </p>
    <font class="font-teacher">
        <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmouseup="GoToTheLink(2, 1, '2318!ФАДЭТ!3')">АС-306</a>
    </font>
    <p>5-10</p>
    <br>
    <p>
        <font class="font-subject">Основы автоматизации проектно-конструкторских работ</font>
        <br>
        <font class="font-classroom">
           <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmouseup="GoToTheLink(2, 3, 339)">2-510</a>
        </font>
        <font class="font-teacher"></font>
    </p>
    <p>
        <font class="font-teacher">Лекция + практика</font>
    </p>
    <font class="font-teacher">
        <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmouseup="GoToTheLink(2, 1, '2318!ФАДЭТ!3')">АС-306</a>
    </font>
    <p>11-17</p>
</td>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

#Ищем нужный тег td
td = soup.find("td")

#Ищем нужные нам теги p
result = td.find_all("p", recursive=False, text=re.compile("(\d+(-\d+)?)(, \d+(-\d+)?)*"))

print(result) #[<p>5-10</p>, <p>11-17</p>]
```

Comment: ваш алгоритм будет искать среди всех элементов, а необходимо только у потомков первого уровня. К тому же данная регулярка ищет только по определенному шаблону, он может быть разным, примеры текста добавил

Comment: У потомков кого? Тега `td`? Тогда будет отдельной задачей найти тег `td`, у которого мы будем искать потомков первого уровня.

Comment: тег td уже найден, но метод find_all ищет среди всех потомков, а необходимо только у первого уровня. Почему это важно. Попадется такой же элемент в такой же регуляркой, и он попадет в найденные элементы, хотя не является потомком первого уровня элемента td

Comment: Исправил. С параметром `recursive=False` функция `find_all` ищет только потомков первого уровня.

Comment: вот, теперь нужно искать только те элементы, у которого больше нет потомков